# pyautogui.locateOnScreen not functioing in the way I expected?

Tags: python

```
while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Day.png", confidence=0.8) != None:
        print("See it")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("Can't see")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This code is meant to check if a particular image is on the screen with locateOnScreen. If it isn't, it returns "can't see". When I show the script the image, it works perfectly fine and prints "see it". When I hide the image, this happens:

Why doesn't it return "Can't see"?

I tried try and except, but that resulted in the same message.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.